# Navigation bar title color does not change if back button is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

Changing the color of the title in the navigation bar does not work if back button is tapped.

There is a UINavigationController.

Its `rootViewController` is VC1. The color of the title in the navigation bar is set to red.

VC1 pushes VC2. The color of the title in the navigation bar is set to green.

When VC2 is popped, the color of the title in the navigation bar is set to red.

If the back button is used to pop VC2, the title of the navigation bar does not change to red and remains green.

If the swipe back gesture is used to pop VC2, the title of the navigation bar changes to red as expected.

The navigation controller is its own delegate.
Using the `navigationController(_:willShow:animated)` method, the color of the tile in the navigation bar is set.

```swift
extension NavigationController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(
        _ navigationController: UINavigationController,
        willShow viewController: UIViewController,
        animated: Bool
        ) {
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .foregroundColor: viewController is VC1 ? UIColor.red : UIColor.green
        ]
        navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = navigationBar.titleTextAttributes?.merging(attributes) { $1 }
    }
}
```

Expected- After the VC2 is popped, the color of the title in the navigation bar should change to red.

Actual- After the VC2 is popped, the color of the title in the navigation bar remains green.

Can anyone point out how to solve this issue, so that the color of the title in the navigation bar becomes red after VC2 is popped out?

Comment: iOS-13? Have you tried to change to it in viewWillAppear of the root ViewController?

Comment: iOS- 12.2. Changing it in viewWillAppear did not make any difference. The issue is still observed.

Comment: So try to change it in viewWillDisappear of the VC2 ViewController

Answer (score 1):

Do this in ViewDidLoad()

```
let image = UIImage(named: "back")
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = image
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = image
        self.navigationItem.title = "Servicos"
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

Answer (score 0):

If both of the viewController has large title enabled. Otherwise use `titleTextAttributes`. It is required that the two of your ViewControllers' UINavigationController's `delegate` is `NavigationController`

```
extension NavigationController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if let _ = viewController as? ToViewController {
            let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.red]
            navigationController.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = textAttributes
        } else {
            let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.green]
            navigationController.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = textAttributes
        }
    }
}
```

This worked for me. Both of my viewControllers has large title.